# Why use different error numbers for THROW?

Tags: sql, vb.net, error-handling, throw

I'm using a stored procedure to insert into a table, and first checking to be sure the data is valid. If it isn't, I'm using `throw` to throw an error:

```sql
;THROW 50000, @Msg, 1;
```

The [specifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) say the error number must be between 50000 and 2147483647 (inclusive). Is there some reason I shouldn't just use 50000 for all of errors I `throw`?

My code would generally consider any SQL errors to be integration errors, or I would check the text of the error message. Is there some best practice for numbering I can't see?

If it's relevant, my code is in VB.NET, but I imagine it should apply to any program.

Comment: Because different errors could mean different things. Throwing the same number for every error that may occur doesn't help much when diagnosing the errors.

Comment: Yes, I can see the message part being different. But why use the error number other than you have to?

Comment: Because an error number can signify a specific type of error, regardless of the text. It can also help with organizing error logs and producing statistics on error frequency and etc. A number is also more lightweight. The list of reasons go on and on. You should not use the same number for each error. Use distinct numbers and create a document for reference that associates each error number with an error type.

Comment: So it is recommended to make documentation somewhere that says 50000 means this, 50001 means that, and 1048576 means something else? But putting the information in the message itself is self-documenting.

Comment: You are free to use whatever error codes you wish. You can even use the same ones if that is what you really want to do. You are assuming that all of the useful information is included in `@Msg` but that isn't true in many cases. Consider a case where you want to reuse error code 50000 for a specific error type, such as "Invalid parameters." That same error type could be used across multiple stored procedures whenever a user provides invalid parameter types or data. The message itself may contain more verbose information, which may only be useful in cases where you care beyond the error type.

Comment: Again, `@Msg` may include specifics such as what parameters triggered the error. But the error code represents the type of error more broadly. If you don't find this useful in your application, you can use error code 50000 for everything. But your question is "_Is there some reason I shouldn't just use 50000 for all of errors I throw?"_ to which I've provided multiple reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using a stored procedure to insert into a table, and first checking to be sure the data is valid. If it isn't, I'm using throw to throw an error

The first thing to consider is that not every instance of throwing an error is because of invalid data. In a stored procedure, there are many scenarios where you may decide to throw an error explicitly.

The primary point of associating number codes with errors is for categorizing errors. Consider the following potential error categories:

```
50000 - Invalid data
50001 - Stored Procedure Already Executed Today (for daily jobs)
50002 - Timeout
50003 - Referential Integrity Conflict
...
```

Just because you may only be throwing an error for a specific error category doesn't mean SQL servers should only support a single category of errors. Developers are free to come up with as many error categories as they wish (within the constraints of 50000-2147483647).

Also worth noting is that `@Msg` may not be enough information in some cases. The code you've provided is generic so we don't know what `@Msg` is, but it could have specifics beyond the error category, such as "What about the data was invalid for inserting into this table?" Because of this, the `@Msg` may be different for various errors thrown within the same stored procedure. That makes it very difficult to go through error logs and do things such as aggregate the most commonly occurring errors.

You are free to use whatever error number convention you wish within your application. However, there are many reasons why developers may choose to not use 50000 for all of the errors they throw. One of the main considerations for using different error codes is to classify errors by category. From there, anything from driving additional business logic or aggregating error logs and more can be performed.

Comment: My specific error (and I have only one for this purpose so far; editing an existing application) is `DECLARE @Msg NVARCHAR(200) = FORMATMESSAGE('InventoryID %i and LocationID %i not allowed per the CMS_Location_Container_Lnk table.', @InventoryID, @LocationID)`. I don't intend to check my error in the code, since it is outside specifications, and already has error handling around the update. So far, I find your answer somewhat useful, but am waiting to see if anything better come up.

Comment: Even in the case that you've described, the `@Msg` data is dynamically generated and thus you would be unable to efficiently aggregate these errors if you eventually decided to add new error categories in different stored procedures. If you are only ever going to use a single error type (a bold assumption for any developer building an application), then you can use the same error code. The point of the codes is to allow for expanding the types of errors than can occur and how they are handled.

Comment: @MichaelFoster since it has now been a few weeks have you reconsidered accepting this answer? The primary point is just because you don't currently intend to use more than a single error code doesn't mean you may not have uses for others in the future. That and developers are free to build their applications as they wish - using or disregarding whatever features a language or framework may provide. So you don't have to use more than one code in your application, but others may choose to and shouldn't be prevented from doing so. To this day even C/C++ executables and others return status codes.